# How to Authorize AD users with .Net Core

Tags: authorization, asp.net-core

I'm trying to stop requests on a route using the `Authorize` annotation, but I can't get it to work with Active Directory. Had anyone got this working yet?

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles = "DOMAIN\\Group A")]
[Route("/")] // GET: /
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Note: I've also tried `Authorize(Roles = @"DOMAIN\\Group A")`

Just to give some background, I'm running Windows, Visual Studio Pro 2015 (Update 3)

Heres a bit from my project.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Swashbuckle.SwaggerGen": "6.0.0-beta901",
    "Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi": "6.0.0-beta901"
  }
```

Comment: Are you speaking of the in "Windows Authentication" option when creating a new project? Or do you want to use i.e. identity to register against an AD via LDAP or similar mechanism? Later one is unsupported (therefore no out of the box solution due to security concerns), so you'd have to implement your own provider for it. Also, I **believe** that Windows Authorization will just log you in, but you won't have the roles on it. Check the IPrincipal/ClaimsPrincipal on the claims loaded to see if there is a role claims on it or not

Comment: @Tseng I've already got Authentication, I need Authorisation (The "can you do x", not "who are you"). Also, the users are in the same domain as the server. If I have to use a separate package for LDAP auth, can you recommend one?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you configured both IIS and the app for integrated authentication?

In your web.config do you have the asp.net core module set to forward Windows Identities, by setting `forwardWindowsAuthToken="true"`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" 
        modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" 
      arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
      stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In your program.cs have you plumbed in IIS integration with `.UseIISIntegration()`?

```cs
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseIISIntegration()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();
```

Have you added authorization in your ConfigureServices() method in Startup.cs and put it before AddMvc()?

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthorization();
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

When I have all those things in place I can happily authorize based on roles, for example I put `[Authorize(Roles = "REDMOND\\scottgu_org_fte")]` on my home controller and I get in just fine.

Using `@"REDMOND\\scottgu_org_fte"` won't work, because that makes the string literal [verbatim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx), so it's trying to evaluate `Domain\\group`, and double slashes are wrong. `@"REDMOND\scottgu_org_fte"` would work though.

Comment: Turned out I forgot to add `services.AddAuthorization();`

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks for the info. I had to add the web.config file with the forwardWindowsAuthToken attribute manually though, as described here: [https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/26751/publish-aspnet-core-to-iis-with-windows-authentica.html](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/26751/publish-aspnet-core-to-iis-with-windows-authentica.html)

Comment: Looks like manually adding 'forwardWindowsAuthToken="true"' to the web.config is not necessary anymore per the above reference: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/26751/publish-aspnet-core-to-iis-with-windows-authentica.html. Also verified in app.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.

Comment: Except when you specify the [`AuthenticationSchemes = "Windows"` this stops working ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54877368/specifying-windows-authenticationscheme-and-roles-doesnt-work)

Comment: @spottedmahn That's because you've made assumptions here in how it works.

Comment: @blowdart fair enough, set me straight! 

Answer (score 1):

If you just wish to allow / deny users as per standard MVC, and use IIS reverse proxy to Kestrel, then you can add a web.config and add

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <authorization>
      <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
      <add accessType="Allow" roles="my AD User Group" />
      <add accessType="Allow" roles="uk\myUsercode" />
    </authorization>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```