# ASP.NET Core Authentication Novell.Directory.Ldap

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm using the Novell.Directory.Ldap library to get communication between my intranet application and an Active Directory server.

However I need to implement an authentication where I verify if the user is authenticated in my local network and is part of a certain group.

All the user verification logic with the AD and if it is part of this particular group is already ready using the library mentioned above. However, I need this to work alongside ASP.NET authentication.

Has anyone implemented anything like this and can you help me with this?

Comment: This is not a good idea. Front your service on IIS and enable Windows Auth. You can configure everything you want in IIS.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: Windows Authentication is already enabled. Once the user is authenticated in Windows, I check if it exists in AD and if it is part of a certain group.

Comment: ?? If windows auth is already enabled, then the user is necessarily an existing user in active directory. If IIS forwards credentials to your app, then you should have all claims of the user, including its groups. You can then add authorization to your middlewares and everything should work as expected. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895141/how-to-authorize-ad-users-with-net-core)

Comment: Have you solved your issue?